# Assistance converting LINQ code to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many to many relationship and "MyTable" is my relator Relational between "Stores" table and "Products" Table and I have a LINQ query to sum how many of product have I in store id but I want this SQL query:

```
user.MyTable.Where(i => i.StoreID == storeid).Sum(i => i.Count * user.Products.First(j => j.ProductID == i.ProductID).Sellprice);
```

Comment: Have a go and let us know when stuck

Comment: Can you show database tables?

Comment: should be something like this `SELECT SUM(Sellprice) FROM MyTable MyTable
INNER JOIN Products Products
ON Products.ProductID = MyTable.ProductId
WHERE StoreId = yourStoreId`

Comment: @dalek i want to use it on my windows form application cause it use sqlite database

Comment: If you want SQLite then why tag SQL Server? And I was suggesting you have a go yourself before asking. Also show your requirements i.e. sample data and desired results. Otherwise very hard to know if an answer meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(i.Count * j.SellPrice)
FROM MyTable i
JOIN Products j ON j.ProductID = i.ProductID
WHERE i.StoreID = storeid;
```

could work.